# Preapproved, pre-approved or pre approved?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

Just wondering which is correct in this sentence:

***And, I think that was someone spamming, pretending to have a convo.
Because they have to be preapproved before they show up on my blog.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If it's about spelling,** don't bother much. Both are in practice. Some examples from COCA. But yes, don't use 'pre approved'.

> "This is one of the reasons it is so important for buyers to talk with a loan officer and get pre-approved before they start looking," he said. - *Chicago Sun-Times*
>
> In the aftermath of 9/11, they have emerged as advocates of border controls that enhance security without hampering trade flows, such as the expedited passage of pre-approved trucks - *Hemisphere, A Magazine of the Americas*

And...

> But chemical dispersants aren't preapproved for use in Alaska and would be considered only when other response measures aren't working - *Environmental Health Perspectives*
>
> So I pulled out my computer, looked up the UnitedHealthcare list of preapproved doctors and started calling - *Washington Post*

---

It's interesting to know that both the formats have been used in *almost* equal frequencies (COCA results of 48 *'pre-approved'* over 59 *'preapproved'*).

Answer (score 2):

None of them are correct.

In your example you would simply say *approved*.

The addition of the prefix *pre* has no meaning for words such as *approve*.
It implies something that is done before approval.  Therefore, pre-approved means not yet approved.

You do find meaningless phrases like pre-approved and pre-booked used by marketers and advertisers but they cannot be recommended in good English.

Comment: In the most common usage I can think of, you can receive a credit card offer where you are "preapproved". The offer is based on your credit report, but the card may or may not be issued to you depending on other information you provide. In this situation, you could not say "approved" in the original offer.

Answer (score 1):

> pre approved

is wrong because you can't separate a prefix to be a word by itself.

> preapproved

is the best choice. A quick dictionary check only lists [***preapprove***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/preapprove), not pre-approve.

I could find some usage of *pre-approved* but that might just be poor usage.

Comment: *Preeclampsia* is a word, but 'Pre-eclampsia' is also okay.